# When the main exits where does the console output go?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;
void func()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)cout << "Print" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    thread t(func);
    t.detach();
    cout << "Exit" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, when the main exits, where does the `"Print"`text would be gone,since it doesn't have an output stream? Is there any dummy stream for inserting data which has no use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `main` exits it calls `exit` which terminates all threads, regardless detached or not. This is because `exit` terminates the entire process.

The C++ runtime runs `main` as `exit(main(argc, argv))`, so that returning from `main` causes `exit` to be called.

You can terminate your main thread, if you wish, by calling `pthread_exit`. In this case the main thread will not return from `main` and will not call `exit`. The application will keep running until some other thread calls `exit` or all threads terminate (or the application crashes). This is how it works on Linux, not sure about Windows.

`std::cout` object and the other standard streams are available at least until `exit` is called. These streams are initialized using [Schwarz Counter idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter), which makes sure they get initialized before its first use and destroyed after the last user is gone. In other words, if you have a global object with a constructor and destructor, which gets initialized before `main` is entered and destroyed after (when `exit` is called), that standard stream is still going to be available in that global object destructor. Basically, there is a reference counter associated with each standard stream, each translation unit (object file) increments this reference counter on the startup and decrements on termination.

ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E) says:

> **27.4 Standard iostream objects**
>
> 27.4.1.2 The objects [the standard streams] are constructed and the associations are established at some time prior to or during the first time an object of class `ios_base::Init` is constructed, and in any case before the body of `main` begins execution†. The objects are not destroyed during program execution. The results of including  in a translation unit shall be as if  defined an instance of `ios_base::Init` with static storage duration. Similarly, the entire program shall behave as if there were at least one instance of `ios_base::Init` with static storage duration.
>
> † **Constructors and destructors for static objects can access these objects to read input from `stdin` or write output to `stdout` or `stderr`.**

Comment: "std::cout object and the other standard streams are available until exit is called" is only enough as an answer i guess.

Comment: Hmm. There's still the question open, if `cout` is destroyed (1) before the thread terminates,(2) after or (3) if the order is actually undefined. (1) and (3) could yield interesting results ...

Comment: Isn't again the definition of detach operation? Once I make a thread detached why would it exit when main function terminates. I am not using any variables of main inside func. So it is neither an undefined behaviour.

Comment: One could argue that [*destructors of objects with static storage duration are called in reverse order of completion of their constructors or the completion of their dynamic initialization, and the functions passed to std::atexit are called in reverse order they are registered (last one first).*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) tells us that, since cout probably existed before the static thread list, it gets cleaned up after. But it's not as explicit as I would like.

Comment: @InQusitive _Once I make a thread detached why would it exit when main function terminates_ - because returning from `main` causes `exit` to be called. libc invokes `main` like `exit(main(argc, argv))`. And `exit` is required to terminate all threads, regardless detached or not.

Comment: @dhke `std::cout` and other standard streams initialized using schwarz counter. That means they are created before its first user and destroyed after the last user is gone. In other words, you would have to try hard to have `std::cout` destroyed under you.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Okay, that's the implementation detail that guarantees all works out well. But I'm still curious if this is actually specified somewhere, because "*cout is valid until exit is called*" isn't enough since we are *inside* exit when the threads get terminated.

Comment: @dhke Cited the standard for you.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Thanks a lot for the research: The important part is: "*the objects are not destroyed during program execution.*". Hence cout needs to stick as long as some part of your program has access to it.